# Continue HTTP Video Live streaming In background mode Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am searching for an answer related to live streaming for a while but did not got any satisfying answer.

I am developing a HTTP live streaming (HLS) protocol  based ios app. I can live stream from my ios app  that not a problem . but when my  app goes in background by pressing home button The Mpmovieplayer get paused and after returning to the foreground when i resume the player it take some time for starting  to live streaming again. Thats normally its behaves.

But now my client wants that after returning to foreground from background the live streaming should not take time . that means in my understanding the continuous request of url should be done in background so that when app come to foreground the live streamjing should take very little time .

My question is how i can request  to live straming url in background mode so that that steaming goes smoothly after coming from  background . I have searched the documentation the closest think i got is audio live streaming in background.Anyone there who can enlighten me how other ios live streaming app solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

You can make a circular buffer for that for something like 10 secs and keep feeding the data in it and deleting it on other side so you will ways have say 10 secs of data. Whenever the player goes to background, even then you will keep filling the buffer. Whenever it comes back, fed the player with the buffer and after say 8-9 secs you can switch to normal streaming.

I am not sure if this will be feasible fro your application but its workable and people have implemented this kind of behavior.